# Is is possible to write typesafe function for discriminated unions where input is object whose keys are discriminant of its corresponding values

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to write following `sum` function for discriminated union types?

- 1st arg = `tag` is a discriminant
- 2nd arg = `object` for which `key` = `discriminant` (this should be equal to `value[tag]`) and `value` is one of the shape from discriminated union

for example:

```js
// how to add restriction for keys of members so that, key = A[K][tag]
const sum = <T extends string>(tag: T) => <A>(members: { [K in keyof A]: A[K] }) => {
  // ...
  throw new Error('')
}

type Shape = { kind: 'circle'; radius: number } | { kind: 'square'; x: number }

// should compile
sum('kind')({
  circle: { kind: 'circle', radius: 10 },
  square: { kind: 'square', x: 10 }
})

// should not compile as square is not correct discriminant for its corresponding value
sum('kind')({
  square: { kind: 'circle', radius: 10 },
  circle: { kind: 'circle', radius: 10 }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, following code does the trick:

```js
type Shape = { kind: 'circle'; radius: number } | { kind: 'square'; x: number }

const sum = <T extends string>(tag: T) => <A>(
  members: {
    [K in keyof A]: A[K] extends { [Key in T]: K } & Record<string, unknown> ? A[K] : never
  }
) => {
  // ...
}

// compiles!!!
sum('kind')({
  circle: { kind: 'circle', radius: 10 },
  square: { kind: 'square', x: 10 }
})

// does not compile!!!
sum('kind')({
  square: { kind: 'circle', radius: 10 },
  circle: { kind: 'circle', radius: 10 }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be done - but you'll need to provide a generic type for the union. Without passing a parameter for this type it's not possible for TS to error out when you supply an incorrect property, because it doesn't have anything to validate against.

So that could look something like this:

```js
type StringProperties<O extends object> = {[key in keyof O]: O[key] extends string ? key : never }[keyof O];

type ExtractByTag<
  O extends object, // Object union to extract from
  K extends StringProperties<O>, // Key to use
  P, // property value to extract
> = O extends { [key in K]: P } ? O : never;

const sum = <T extends string>(tag: T) => <
  O extends { [key in T]: string },
>(members: {[key in S[T]]: ExtractByTag<O, T & StringProperties<O>, key> }) => {
  return members;
}
```

This isn't great though - because now you have to explicitly refine the type inside the function to actually do anything useful, as well as implement how this is done - for example:

```js
const isShapesByKey = <
  P extends StringProperties<S>, // 'kind'
  S extends { [key in P]: any } // Shape extends { P: K }
>(key: P, arg: unknown): arg is ShapeKinds<P, S> => {
  // Here you would write custom logic to determine if members is of kind shape
  return true;
}

const sum = <T extends string>(tag: T) => <
  O extends { [key in T]: string },
>(members: {[key in S[T]]: ExtractByTag<O, T & StringProperties<O>, key> }) => {
  if (isShapesByKey<'kind', Shape>('kind', members)) {
    const circle = members.circle;
    const square = members.square;

   // do stuff with shapes
  }

  return members;
}
```

This loses the benefit of being generic at all. At this point you might as well write the much less generic and simpler version:

```js
type ExtractShape<S, K> = S extends { kind: K } ? S : never;

const sum = (members: {[key in Shape['kind']]: ExtractShape<Shape, key>}) => {
  const circle = members.circle;
  const square = members.square;
}
```

So if you want to go down the generic route I would suggest you provide a function which selects the values to sum. That way you can also drop the generic parameter and just supply one for the property selection function which is a bit cleaner:

```js
type StringProperties<O extends object> = {[key in keyof O]: O[key] extends string ? key : never }[keyof O];

type ExtractByTag<
  O extends object, // Object union to extract from
  K extends StringProperties<O>, // Key to use
  P, // property value to extract
> = O extends { [key in K]: P } ? O : never;

const sum = <T extends string>(tag: T) => <
  O extends { [key in T]: string },
>(
  members: {[key in O[T]]: ExtractByTag<O, T & StringProperties<O>, key> },
  propertySelector: (extractFrom: O) => number
) => {
  return Object.values<O>(members).reduce((prev, next) => {
    return prev + propertySelector(next);
  }, 0);
})

// Usage 
sum('kind')({
  circle: { kind: 'circle', radius: 10 }, // OK 
  square: { kind: 'square', x: 10 }, // OK
}, (shape: Shape) => {
  switch(shape.kind) {
    case 'circle':
      return shape.radius;
    case 'square':
      return shape.x;
  }
});

// Should not compile as square is not correct discriminant for its corresponding value
sum('kind')<Shape>({
  square: { kind: 'square', x: 10 }, // OK
  circle: { kind: 'circle', x: 10 }, // ERROR
}, (shape: Shape) => {
  switch(shape.kind) {
    case 'circle':
      return shape.radius;
    case 'square':
      return shape.x;
  }
});
```